# Azure SQL: What is the cost of running a specific SQL query like create database as copy

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-webjobs, azure-sql-server

What are the costs of running the following operation in Azure?

```
drop database MyDB;
create database MyDB as copy of MyDB_Clean;
```

The scope of the above operation is to restore an existing database to its clean version to improve web site performance.

It will run once every day via an Azure web job and would like to assess if this would be feasible in terms of costs.

`MyDB_Clean` used space = 35 MB, allocated space 48 MB, using Tiers S0/S1/S2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What are the costs of running the following operation in Azure?

Just the cost for the two databases, and if they fit in a single Elastic Pool, there would be no additional cost.  See the [Pricing Page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/managed/) for the different pricing models.

Comment: does this mean that strictly the operation to create the new database via that script does not incur any costs?

Comment: Right.  Generally in Azure SQL Database you pay for reserved resources.  Using those resources does not incur any additional cost.

Comment: @alex, based on your selection of pricing tier- serverless or provisioned; you would get charged. If its provisioned, there would be static cost every month and you can choose to do whatever with it. if its serverless, the cost would be based on your usage- IO, CPU and Memory.  Regarding your question on copy command I can not answer it. but if your pricing is provisioned then there is 0 cost.